# position view relative to tab indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've been given a UI that uses a `UITabBarController`, and in one of the tabbed `ViewControllers`, a `View` (an arrow as a `UIImageView`) needs to be positioned relative to the tab indicator (the arrow needs to point down at the indicator, centered along the x-axis).  I used basic math to emulate the position based on known variables, and it works properly for iPhone/Pod in both landscape and portrait orientations, but fails on iPad (it's a little too far right in both orientations - seems worse in landscape but that might just be my perception).

Here's what I used:

```
int visibleWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
int tabBarSize = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width;
int tabSize = tabBarSize / [self.tabBarController.viewControllers count];
int tabPosition = 2; // hint should point at the 3rd tab
int arrowIconWidth = hintIcon.image.size.width;
int arrowIconHeight = hintIcon.image.size.height;

int tabEmulationPosition = visibleWidth / 2 - tabBarSize / 2;
int tabOffsetPosition = tabEmulationPosition + ( tabSize * tabPosition );
int iconPosition = tabOffsetPosition + ( tabSize / 2 - arrowIconWidth / 2 );
```

Is there a better way than trying to "fake" the math (maybe a `getBoundingClientRect` type method?)  Or is the math approach the best bet, assuming there's a correct-able flaw in what I've got?

TYIA

Answer (score 0):

Your math seems alright except one *caveat*: the Core Graphics distances are all of type `CGFloat` not `int`. Remember that integer division works differently in C than what you might expect:

```
int x = 5 / 2; // x == 2
```

Thus, replace your `int`s with `CGFloat`s and divide by 2.0 rather than 2.

Also, in the iPad the tab button are not necessarily spaced evenly across the whole bar but have a certain padding to the left and right. You would have to fiddle for finding a suitable constant, or experimentally find a reliable way to calculate it based on the number of view controllers.

Assuming a fixed tab bar button width, you could calculate an offset to add to the x of your image:

```
CGFloat tabSize = 
   FIXED_TAB_BUTTON_WIDTH * self.tabBarController.viewControllers.count;
CGFloat offset = (tabBarSize - tabSize) / 2.0;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I've replaced with floats but the effect is the same.  In iPad portrait, the arrow looks like it's just inside the correct tab but at the extreme right.  In iPad landscape, it's even a little farther right, and appears to be at the left edge of the adjacent tab indicator.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe the reason is that the buttons in the tab bar are centered and not spaced evenly across the whole tab bar, but with two margins. You assume they are evenly spaced in line 3 of your code. See my edit for a solution.